# How to remove spacing between figure and caption in the beamer class

Tags: beamer, floats, captions

i'm creating a presentation with the latex beamer class and want to change the spacing between the figure and the caption. I think it is to large at the moment.

```
\documentclass[xcolor=dvipsnames]{beamer}
\usetheme{Luebeck}
\setbeamercolor{structure}{fg=PineGreen}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[german]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\newcommand*\oldmacro{}%
\let\oldmacro\insertshorttitle%
\renewcommand*\insertshorttitle{%
  \oldmacro\hfill%
  \insertframenumber\,/\,\inserttotalframenumber}

\setbeamertemplate{itemize items}[triangle]
\setbeamerfont{caption}{size=\tiny}


\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Tresholding - OpenCV-Methoden}

\centering
\begin{minipage}{.5\textwidth}
    \centering
    \begin{figure}
        \includegraphics[width=.8\linewidth]{images/treshold_otsu.png}
        \caption{Otsu Tresholding}
    \end{figure}
\end{minipage}%
\begin{minipage}{.5\textwidth}
    \centering
    \begin{figure}
        \includegraphics[width=.8\linewidth]{images/treshold_adaptive.png}
        \caption{Adaptive Tresholding}
    \end{figure}
\end{minipage}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

How could that be achieved?
Here is an image of the slide:

[image: Image of a slide with the spacing marked]

Comment: If you are creating slides and don't intend to create a list of figures, then you really don't need either figure or caption.  Use a tabular instead.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The proper way to do this is to redefine `\abovecaptionskip` so the change in vertical spacing will consistently apply to *all* the captions; in the example below I used

```
\setlength\abovecaptionskip{-5pt}
```

but you can change the value in the argument according to your needs.

```
\PassOptionsToPackage{demo}{graphicx}
\documentclass[xcolor=dvipsnames]{beamer}
\usetheme{Luebeck}
\setbeamercolor{structure}{fg=PineGreen}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[german]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{textcomp}

\newcommand*\oldmacro{}%
\let\oldmacro\insertshorttitle%
\renewcommand*\insertshorttitle{%
  \oldmacro\hfill%
  \insertframenumber\,/\,\inserttotalframenumber}

\setbeamertemplate{itemize items}[triangle]
\setbeamerfont{caption}{size=\tiny}

\setlength\abovecaptionskip{-5pt}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Tresholding - OpenCV-Methoden}

\centering
\begin{minipage}{.5\textwidth}
    \centering
    \begin{figure}
        \includegraphics[width=.8\linewidth]{images/treshold_otsu.png}
        \caption{Otsu Tresholding}
    \end{figure}
\end{minipage}%
\begin{minipage}{.5\textwidth}
    \centering
    \begin{figure}
        \includegraphics[width=.8\linewidth]{images/treshold_adaptive.png}
        \caption{Adaptive Tresholding}
    \end{figure}
\end{minipage}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

The result:

[image]

The line `\PassOptionsToPackage{demo}{graphicx}` simply replaces actual figures with black rectangles; delete that line in your actual document.

Comment: There is also a `\belowcaptionskip` which is particularly useful for tables (since their caption is usually on top).

Answer (score 6):

You can do it manually by using `\vspace*{-0.3cm}` (or whatever distance you like) in front of the caption.

```
\documentclass[xcolor=dvipsnames]{beamer}
\usetheme{Luebeck}
\setbeamercolor{structure}{fg=PineGreen}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[german]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\newcommand*\oldmacro{}%
\let\oldmacro\insertshorttitle%
\renewcommand*\insertshorttitle{%
  \oldmacro\hfill%
  \insertframenumber\,/\,\inserttotalframenumber}

\setbeamertemplate{itemize items}[triangle]
\setbeamerfont{caption}{size=\tiny}


\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Tresholding - OpenCV-Methoden}

\centering
\begin{minipage}{.5\textwidth}
    \centering
    \begin{figure}
        \includegraphics[width=.8\linewidth]{example-grid-100x100bp.pdf}
        \vspace*{-0.3cm}
        \caption{Otsu Tresholding}
    \end{figure}
\end{minipage}%
\begin{minipage}{.5\textwidth}
    \centering
    \begin{figure}
        \includegraphics[width=.8\linewidth]{example-grid-100x100bp.pdf}
        \vspace*{-0.3cm}
        \caption{Adaptive Tresholding}
    \end{figure}
\end{minipage}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: But then you need to do this for each caption.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [`caption` package](http://mirror.easyname.at/ctan/macros/latex/contrib/caption/caption-eng.pdf) for this:

```
\usepackage[skip=2pt]{caption} % example skip set to 2pt
```

This will effect all figures.

The documentation says:

> The vertical space between the caption and the figure or table contents is controlled by the option skip=amount. The standard LATEX document classes
>   article, report and book preset it to skip=10pt, but other document classes may use a different amount.